# Footer layer not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use layers in my html page. The header, anv, section and aside show but the footer does not show up.

I have checked and validated the html and css. I was thinking there is a fixed height that doesnt allow it, but there is not so, I don't know

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1260px;
  min-width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

section {
  background-color: #151B8D;
  width: 60%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
  <title><i>Test Layout</i></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=" container ">
    <header>
      <h1>Test Layout</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <section>
    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the footer to show, I know it is a basic problem and pretty boring css. The problem is I do not know the issue as the code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

The other sections have float:left which means that they do not push down your footer like you want it to.

Your footer is hidden behind your other sections a quick fix could be to add float:left to the footer as well

check this fiddle for example on where it works

```
footer {
background-color:#00FF00;
width:100%;
height:200px;
float:left;
font-size:100px;
text-align:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rojzy94u/

Answer (score 0):

Use     `position: fixed;` and 
    `bottom: 0;`

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1260px;
  min-width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

section {
  background-color: #151B8D;
  width: 60%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Test Layout</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <section>
  </section>
  <aside>
  </aside>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou both, it still won't show for some reason, in firefox or IE but it works when I test the code snippet. edit: I validated it again, and it wasn't showing a color, both suggestions were good and worked well

Comment: When you answer make sure to answer on a reply and not creating a reply on your own question or we won't get any notifications.
I've updated my reply with a link

Answer (score 0):

Add clear: left; to your footer. That should solve your problem.

```
footer {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I respect all the answer but problem is its hiding under section, make it `clear:both`. It will work.

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1260px;
  min-width: 780px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

section {
  background-color: #151B8D;
  width: 60%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  width: 20%;
  height: 768px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
  <title><i>Test Layout</i></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=" container ">
    <header>
      <h1>Test Layout</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
    </nav>
    <section>
    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```